# Windows 8 doesn't boot normally, just in safe mode

Tags: windows-8, boot, reinstall, reboot, safe-mode

I had win7, which was working perfectly. I put in a win8 disk, and chose upgrade install option, which instead of resetting the pc, just upgrades from one os to another, without losing data, settings, and programs. I found out a little problem. My pc won't restart. It can shutdown, and then start, but not restart. When I was installing my drivers, one driver asked me to restart, and when I did, it kept on restarting at the loading screen. So, I put my disk back in, and through my BIOS, opened it. Chose the repair options, and finally, chose the Automatic Repair option, and my windows started.

I tried one whole day to fix this restart problem, so that in the future, I can restart. My pc was working fine, except that it wasn't able to restart, when suddenly something happened and it won't boot at all, only it keeps on restarting when at the loading screen. I tried to open it in Safe mode, and it worked. Now, my windows only opens in Safe mode. I tried to re-install windows through 2 methods:-

1)I tried to re-install by booting the bootable disk through my BIOS. It asked me to install through the windows.

2)I tried to install by opening windows in safe mode, and it asked me to open normal mode instead of the safe mode.
Please give me a solution which would help me solving my problem, without losing any data, and installed programs.

Comment: What driver caused this problem?   You need to remove the problem driver.

Comment: Now the bios has even stopped from booting. Before there used to be an Intel screen which gave options to boot from another drive, etc. Now it's showing the words 'EB'. My motherboard is intel DH61WW.

Comment: I am sure that driver is not the problem, beacause, when windows loaded for the first time, it hanged, and i restarted, since then my pc stopped restarting, and now the problem has increased, now my bios wont even load.

Comment: Most recent motherboards have a mechanic to restore the BIOS from a recovery backup.  If yours does not then you are sadly out of luck.

Comment: That EB error was due to my External Hardrive. Plus now I've solved all my problems, the msconfig settings I had put for safe boot had the option Maximum Memory(RAM) Ticked and set to 2040mb, which when I removed, my pc started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the microsoft window key in the bottom left portion of your keyboard, tab out of your start screen to your desktop.
2. In the desktop screen, you will notice there is no start button in the lower left corner.  Even though there is no button, there is a hidden "poor man's" start menu.  Placing your cursor in the very bottom left corner of your desktop, right click on that corner.  It might take more than one click.  A menu of sorts pops up.  One of the options is the familiar "run"
3. Left click on run.  When the box pops up ....type in msconfig then hit the enter key on your keyboard.
4. A system configuration box will pop up with several tabs including one that says "boot"
5. Select the boot tab and you will see a safe mode box that has a check mark in it.
6. Uncheck the safe mode box and hit the apply or ok button.
7. You will then see a restart button.  Click it to restart your computer.
8. When your computer comes back up, sign in and you will now be in "normal mode"